# Is it possible to use so = shellout("linux cmd") outside of Chef in ruby script?

Tags: shell, chef-infra, mixlib-shellout

I'm curious, is there a possibility to use shellout in ruby scripts outside of Chef? How to set up this?

Answer (score 1):

`gem install mixlib-shellout`

and in the ruby script

```
require 'mixlib/shellout'
cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new('linux cmd')
cmd.run_command
# And then optionally, to raise an exception if the command fails like shell_out!()
cmd.error!
```

ETA:
If you want to avoid creating the instance yourself, I usually dump this wrapper fucntion in scripts where I use it:

```
def shellout(cmd, ok_exits = [0])
  run = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(cmd)
  run.run_command
  if run.error? || !ok_exits.include?(run.exitstatus)
    puts "#{cmd} failed: #{run.stderr}"
    exit 2
  end
  run.stdout
end
```

Comment: That will only give you the base API, the `shell_out()` helper actually comes from Chef. I'll edit your example :)

Comment: So to summarize `Mixlib::ShellOut.new` should be used? The helper `shell_out` is offered only by Chef?

Comment: `Mixlib::Shellout` is a class, so you need to initialize instances of it.  Chef wraps this in a module which can be included to get the class methods, but it's Chef-environment-dependent.  You could wrap your own module, though.  https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/c1a389c2a8452e9b796aa1d34c4d9e51f4af30c7/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb

Comment: Personally, I define `require 'mixlib/shellout'; def shell_out(cmd); so = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(cmd, timeout: 60); so.run_command; so; end`. This works exactly as Chef component in terms of `stdout`, `stderr` and `exitstatus`. Try `a = shell_out('ls')` and `puts a.stdout`. Mixlib must be installed with gem.